# Squid: cache content for n minutes no matter what

Tags: proxy, http, squid, cache

I am administrating a network for a group of programmers developing a web spider.

We want to setup a squid cache so to be nicer to all those servers in the web. (And also so that our tests run faster).

The configuration we need is very easy: Cache everything for 30 minutes, no matter what (ignore last modified, e-tag, etc).

How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Squid cache cache removal policy are based on disk space usage, not object "age": objects are removed from the cache when space is needed to cache new objects. In other words you should properly set the size with the cache_dir directive to achieve your "30 minutes cache".

The refresh_pattern directive has options that can override or ignore some headers.

I think that a combination of options described here http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/ can help you.